# prevent a std::set from deleting memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, set

Is there a way to prevent a `std::set< Object*>.erase(it)` function to delete memory?
I only want the `Object*` to be removed from the set, without freeing memory..

To be specific, I have an object that removes himself from the set and puts itself to another.
And it crashes.

```
set1.insert(this);    
set1.erase(set1.find(this));
set2.insert(this);
```

Anyone able to reproduce this? thank you!

Comment: can't you use a set< Object* > in the first place? It would require you to handle the lifetime managment yourself though..

Comment: What is the type of your std::set?  `std::set<Object>` or `std::set<Object*>` ?

Comment: @GWW it is a std::set< Object*>

Comment: Are you 100% confident that when `set1.erase(set1.find(this))` is called, `this` is actually present in `set1`?

Comment: @aix yes it is.. I use it in other parts of the class

Comment: Inside which method does it crash? Show us the stack trace please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `set<Object*>` already doesn't delete the pointed-to object when you call the erase for the iterator. If it's crashing in that area it's for another reason. Likely causes are:

- You're using the iterator after you erase the item.
- Missing/incorrect destructor.
- Missing/incorrect copy constructor/copy assignment operator.
- Unrelated problems with the heap such as double deletes.

Comment: I think it would be ok if it just allow me to fire the pointer without worrying about the destructor..
also I don't use deletes in my code now..

Comment: maybe you are right and I'm just too silly to make it work properly.. Thanks to all of you again!

Comment: Fixed now. Your first guess was right: THE ITERATOR XD thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Since you are storing raw pointers in the set, you don't need to do anything special: the memory won't be freed when you call `erase`.

As to what might be causing the crash, please post some relevant code and some details of where exactly it's crashing.

Answer (score 1):

That is already what happens.

The element — the pointer — is destroyed. There is no magic that also `delete`s the thing it's pointing to.

Comment: then I don't know what is happening to me XD thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

What's in your set ? QObject* ? 
If so `erase` should only free your pointer not the instance it is pointing to ...
Your are taking about a tree ? Is that your set you meaning ?